# How to concatenate columns with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

How to concatenate selected columns under each other? My current code concatenates only the last column and even this is in its original position (on right) but I would like it to be on left. I would like my code to select 3 columns and concatenate (so that their new position is on left), then select next 3 columns and concatenate and so on.
Initial data looks like this:
[image: Initial data]

This is the result I would like to get:
[image: Expected result]

But this is the wrong result I get with my current code:
[image: Wrong result]

This is the code I have:

```
import pandas as pd
file = "C:\\Myfile.xlsx"
file1 = pd.read_excel(file, index=False,sheet_name="Sheet1", index_col=0) 


list = [0,3,3,3]
column_beginning = 0
column_end = 3

for value in list:
  column_beginning = column_beginning + value
  column_end = column_end + value 
  x = file1.iloc[:, column_beginning:column_end]
  df = pd.concat([file1, x], ignore_index=True)

df.to_excel("C:\\Myfile_new.xlsx", index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution might just solve your problem, tested it. Seems fine to me.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
columns=df.columns
length=len(columns)
looping_length=int(length/3)
final_df=df.copy()
inter_df=pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(0, looping_length+1):
    temp_df=pd.DataFrame(np.array(df.iloc[:,3*i:3*i+3]))
    inter_df=pd.concat([inter_df, temp_df], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    #print(inter_df)

inter_df=inter_df.rename(columns={0:"Col1",1:"Col2",2:"Col3"})
final_df=pd.concat([final_df, inter_df], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```